# Dose in Apache spark 1.2.1 Standalone cluster, 'number of executors equals to number of SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES'?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

Dose in Apache spark 1.2.1 Standalone cluster, 'number of executors equals to the number of SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES' ?

```
I have done below setting in conf/spark-env.sh

SPARK_EXECUTOR_CORES=4
SPARK_NUM_EXECUTORS=3
SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=2G
```

If not can anyone tell me how to increase number of executors in standalone cluster?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's sure is that you can't have more execturos than the number of cpu on your machine in a standalone cluster!

Comment: @eliasah..Thanks. Do you mean number of cpu or number of cores? CPU and Cores are two different thing, right? correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: okay.got it.But how should I specify the 'number of executors'? Actually I have specified  "SPARK_NUM_EXECUTORS=3",but after running application it is not creating 3 executors(Spark cluster has total 6 cores available).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standalone mode, total executor num equals to the total worker num in your cluster.

`SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=2` in spark-env.sh represent you want to have 2 workers process on each slave. Suppose you have `n` slaves you would have `2n` workers, therefore, `2n` executors for each job.

`SPARK_NUM_EXECUTORS` is not a valid setting.

Comment: So,to control number of executors in stand alone cluster SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES is the only way and number of SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES are equals to the number of executors.right?